# Auto Trigger webcam QR scanner on VB

Tags: vb.net, qr-code, webcam

i have a simple windows form program using Visual Basic that scan QR code using webcam. But my program use two button on scanning, start button to start the webcam and detect button to scan the QR. My question is, how can i make the two button into one, so when i start the webcam, it will automatically scan the QR code in front of it. This is my start and detect button.

```
   Private Sub ButtonStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    StartWebcam()
    TextBox1.Clear()
End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonDetect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    'Scans the received image
    Try
        StopWebcam()
        Reader = New QRCodeDecoder
        TextBox1.Text = Reader.decode(New Data.QRCodeBitmapImage(PictureBox1.Image))
        MsgBox("QR code is detected!")
    Catch ex As Exception
        StartWebcam()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: If i assume correct, then `StartWebcam` does something positive such as turning the webcam on and `StopWebcam` closes/stops the webcam ? but in order to combine these two, share `Scans the received image` part please

Comment: yeah it's like that. After much search i find that i can put a timer and put the code of the detect button inside its Timer_Tick subroutine, and set its interval. But i don't know how to do it. i'm pretty new in VB

Comment: You don't need a timer.....Just explain a bit clearly what you want to do...It'll be better if you provide an example ...

Comment: Check out [this demo](https://demo.dynamsoft.com/DBR_Webcam/WebcamBarcodeReader.html). It's a web demo app for reading barcode and QR from webcam, but the idea should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

May be is a long shot but you can try combining it like that (I assume that the main button will be `Button1`)

```
Private Sub ButtonStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    StartWebcam()
    TextBox1.Clear()
    Try
        StopWebcam()
        Reader = New QRCodeDecoder
        TextBox1.Text = Reader.decode(New Data.QRCodeBitmapImage(PictureBox1.Image))
        MsgBox("QR code is detected!")
    Catch ex As Exception
        StartWebcam()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Hope I helped or at least gave you some ideas :)

Comment: I don't like downvoting but the reason it won't work is because you are calling `StopWebcam` after the code inside `Try` statement which is not what the OP did...

Comment: @zackraiyan it was my bad. I just realize it as well. I edit my answer following his code and just put the two methods together after each other in a logical way. I am just assuming that it will work. I cannot test it in order to be sure.

Comment: It will work ..it is as simple as that..but i don't think this is what the OP wants at all.....let's wait for his reply

Comment: @Dimitar yeah, i already tried it before and sadly it doesn't work

Comment: Try to take the `StopWebcam()` outside ot the `Try Catch` block and see it will work. If you have the same result I am afraid I have no other ideas for now :(

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong : You want to execute/call `StartWebcam` method and when the execution is done, you want to call the rest of the code right ? If soe, Async/Await is your best option :

```
 ''Firstly,make your StartWebcam method an Async method :

  Async Sub StartWebcam()
  '''codes here
  End sub

  '''Now call the method from your button :    
  TextBox1.Clear()
  Await StartWebcam()

  '''now the other codes that will be executed after StartWebcam is done executing 

   Try
    StopWebcam()
    Reader = New QRCodeDecoder
    TextBox1.Text = Reader.decode(New Data.QRCodeBitmapImage(PictureBox1.Image))
    MsgBox("QR code is detected!")
Catch ex As Exception
    StartWebcam()
End Try
```

Hope this helps :)